# Transactional annotation slows down the performance than HibernateDAOSupport

Tags: spring

I am exporting a report in my code, I am using `HibernateDAOSupport` and the method is not annotated with `@Transactional`. So when the request comes from the UI then automatically Transaction is created and the report is exported in 2 mins.
But when I try to use thread, so I had to put annotation `@Transactional`, otherwise I get an error of LazyInitialization as no Transcaction is present.
So when I put `@Transactional` then the same report takes time 2.4 mins. This time keeps increasing and sometimes it take double of the time without `@Transactional`
I am not sure why it takes time when I put annotation `@Transactional`

The main class:
**CommonDAO**

```
public class CommonDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport
private HibernateTransactionManager txnManager;

    public void setTxnManager(HibernateTransactionManager txnManager) {
        this.txnManager = txnManager;
    }
public List executeSQLQueryPaging(final String hql,
            final Object[] params, final Integer[] pagingParam) throws ServiceException {
        List results = null;
        results = getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback() {

            public Object doInHibernate(Session session) {
                SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
                if (params != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                        query.setParameter(i, params[i]);
                    }
                }
                query.setFirstResult(pagingParam[0]);
                query.setMaxResults(pagingParam[1]);
                return query.list();
            }
        });
        return results;
    }
```

**ModuleDAO extends CommonDAO**

```
public List getReportData{
executeSQLQueryPaging();
...
return list}
```

**Service**

```
public List getReportData(){
.....
return ModuleDAO.getReportData();
}
```

If I put @Transactional at service layer then the performance detriorates, or else it is faster if executed from web.

Comment: [“Talk is cheap. Show me the code.”

― Linus Torvalds](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @emotionlessbananas - Check edited answer, this is simple execution to get data.